# How to keep two tables synchronised in Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I have an orders table that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id INT NOT NULL
  ,customer_id INT NOT NULL
  ,order_date DATE NOT NULL
  ,order_price_total FLOAT NOT NULL
  ,order_price_tax FLOAT NOT NULL
  ,order_discounts FLOAT NOT NULL
  ,order_price_shipping FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

Whenever an order is inserted, updated or deleted, I need to keep another table (called customer_orders) synchronised/up-to-date. Here's what customer_orders should look like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer_orders AS
SELECT
  customer_id
  ,order_id
  ,order_date
  ,order_price_total
  ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date, order_id) AS order_number
  ,COUNT(order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) AS total_customer_orders
  ,LAG(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date, order_id) AS previous_order_date
  ,MIN(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date, order_id) AS first_order_date
  ,order_date - LAG(order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date, order_id) AS previous_order_lookback_days
FROM
  orders;
```

What would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: Or create a view - will always be up-to-date.

Comment: Wouldn't using a view mean that every time customer_orders is queried, all of it's data would need to be re-queried from the orders table? Would it not be better to store all the data in customer_orders permanently and keep it up to date somehow, e.g. a trigger? @jarlh

Comment: Yes, the data is read from the the view's underlying base table(s) when the view is queried. I.e. fresh data is guaranteed. However, if the query has bad performance, the view will be slow. But I'd still start with view based solution and see if I could get the required performance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have that data persisted and synchronized at the same time. That would mean that you rewrite the copy whenever you modify data in the original table, which is a non-starter.

I assume that you are asking because calculating those values for each query is too slow for you. But that's the first thing you should try. The right indexes can help a lot!

The other option is to use a materialized view that you refresh regularly, say every hour. If you are ready to live with stale data in that materialized view, that is a viable solution.